# How to parse out a JSON array from Javascript assignment using regex in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, regex, json

I have the following standard Javascript assignment statement returned as the output form a webservice call. I need to get the JSON array object out of it and was wondering if I can somehow use NSRegularExpression to do that.

I have no control over the web service so it has to continue returning a Javacript assignment stmt as in the attached snippet below.

Can anyone suggest an objective-c code snippet that accomplishes this task? I could receive sub-array and sub hashes as part of the individual elements as well...

```
var collection = [
{
"id": "4444",
"name" : "Bill Smith",
"position" : "tester" 
},
{
"id": "4444",
"name" : "Bill Smith",
"position" : "tester" 
}
];
```

Comment: Can't you just use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: it doesn't like 'var collection =' and the semicolon at the end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh well. I have not found any clever solution to this so I simply took a substring from the entire response object to extract all content between first and last {} or first and last []. Works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
NSArray *myJSONArray = @[
@{
    @"id": @"4444",
    @"name" : @"Bill Smith",
    @"position" : @"tester" 
},
@{
    @"id": @"4444",
    @"name" : @"Bill Smith",
    @"position" : @"tester" 
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSJSONSerialization to take an NSData with your JSON, and parse it into a native Foundation object.

In this case, if you receive the NSData from the JSON snippet you pasted, you'd have an NSArray returned which contains 2 NSDictionary objects. Here is how you can accomplish that using NSJSONSerialization:

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
```

Note that the documentation says:

> The data must be in one of the 5 supported encodings listed in the JSON specification: UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, UTF-32BE. The data may or may not have a BOM. The most efficient encoding to use for parsing is UTF-8, so if you have a choice in encoding the data passed to this method, use UTF-8.

So do ensure that you receive the data in one of those encoded formats. This is the quickest way to do it, it's built in to Cocoa and is very, very fast. Also, you can have different options than **NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves**.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Do you have to receive the data as Javascript from your web service?

It's standard, and probably cleaner, to simply return the raw JSON that your web service produces. This way you don't have to use regex to parse the Javascript and extract the actual JSON contents.

Comment: I tried it but JSONSerlization will like the 'var collection =" and semicolon at the end..I basically receive a javascript assignment statement rather than pure JSON. Never mind....I will just parse the JSON out using basic substrings and indexes...